# Regex: Match double single quote inside string

Tags: regex, quotes

I want a regex that will match for example `'panic can''t happen'` as `panic can''t happen`. Double single quotes are just allowed if they're next to each other, `'panic can't' happen'` sgould be divided into two strings, `panic can` and `happen`.

I got `\'[^\']*[\'\']?[^\']\'` so far but it won't work as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to match OR split?

Comment: Also what language or tool are you using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
'(?:[^']+|'')+'
```

- `'`: Matches a literal `'`.
- `[^']+`: Matches one or more characters which are not `'`.
- `''`: Matches double `''`.
- `(?:[^']+|'')+`: Matches one or more occurrences of the preceding two patterns.
- `'` matches the closing `'`.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pU4pK1)

Comment: +1 for taking a shot on something which wasn't a very clear problem.

Comment: @anubhava LOL. I was a little bored  so I decided why not try to solve the issue, but Thank You of course.

Comment: Excellent, that solved my problem! +1 for extra explanation :)

Comment: @Sniffer I'm just trying to figure it out how it not include single quotes in the match when you are using non-capturing group?

Comment: @Tafari The expression inside the non-capturing group either matches `[^']+` which is one or more non-single quote character, or `|` it matches two single quotes `''`.

Comment: @Sniffer yeah I know but still it's not captured inside the group so you cannot access any **capture groups**. IMHO it should capture everything including the 'outer' single quotes. Even your demo shows that it captures the single quote at the beginning and the end of the phrase.

Comment: @Tafari Ah sorry, you mean you want to exclude the outer single quotes `'` from the match ?

Comment: @Sniffer I thought the OP asked for it in the question but apparently he accepted your answer even if you include the quotes : ) I just wanted to be sure that you actually doesn't exlucde them, as was bit confused about that comparing the answer to the question.

Comment: @Tafari Yes I have included them in the match, if the OP had specified the language or tool he had been using, I would have given him a way to remove the single quotes from match but he seemed satisfied so it is fine by me.

Comment: @Sniffer No doubt you would it's not anything complicated, but as said he asked for not including them and still accepted your answer, thought it might be some regex language as you have mentioned difference or something. Anyway cheers ; )

Answer (score 0):

Well using this pattern will capture double single quotes or split when they are not next to each other:

**PATTERN**

```
'((?:''|[^']+)+)'
```

**INPUT**

'panic can't' happen'

**OUTPUT**

```
Match 1: 'panic can' 
Group 1: panic can
```

And:

```
Match 2: ' happen'
Group 1:  happen
```

**2 case**

**INPUT**

'panic can''t happen'

**OUTPUT**

```
Match 1: 'panic can''t happen' 
Group 1: panic can''t happen
```