# Java Regex Bug with single quote lookup?

Tags: java, regex, string

Probably a PEBKAC which I don't see yet, but: `(?:[^']+|'')+` should match strings with non-double quotation marks (based on [Regex: Match double single quote inside string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263853/regex-match-double-single-quote-inside-string) and tested with [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/pU4pK1/1)).

However, if one uses the above inside a Java Pattern object, i.e., `Pattern noSingleQuote = Pattern.compile("(?:[^']+|'')+");` then the behaviour is as follows:

- If the matched String does not contain single quotes, everything is OK, the Matcher returns true (i.e., `noSingleQuote.matcher("tester").matches()` and `noSingleQuote.matcher("tes''ter").matches()` are OK)
- If the matched String does contain single quotes, then JDK `Matcher` hits an infinite loop internally (i.e., `noSingleQuote.matcher("tes'ter").matches()` results in an infinite loop)

Tested locally on 8u112, and online with [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

I haven't debugged in depth exactly why and where the infinite loop occurs.

Any ideas, insights?

Update: the given examples don't reproduce the described behavoiur, using `"select x, y, z where x = ''t'';"` and `"select x, y, z where x = 't'';"` reproduces what I have described above.
This implies for me, that the bug(?) is not simply because of the single quotes.

Update2: it's not an infinite loop, but it seems to be proportional with the number of spaces in the String itself. Because of the production code where I encountered it has a very long String with a lot of spaces, I just assumed it's an infinite loop. Mea culpa.

Comment: Have you tried escaping `'` chars?

Comment: @I.G.Pascual why?

Comment: .. maybe Java is treating `'` as a special character and needs to be escaped

Comment: @I.G.Pascual I don't see how escaping single quotes would make a difference, nevertheless I tested it: escaping all single quotes with \\ or \\\\ does not make a difference (in the input string nor in the pattern nor in both).

Comment: Just tried the same code locally jdk1.8.0_66 and works perfectly... looks like your jdk is messed up...

Comment: BTW you have a typo on `.matcher()`, should be `matches()`

Comment: Well, you should try `String pattern = "'(?:[^']+|'')+'"`. Why did you omit the leading/trailing `'` in your Java code pattern? Then, just use `String#matches()`. Another thing: Java regex is not good at handling quantified alternations, unroll the pattern as `String pattern = "'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'"`.

Comment: @I.G.Pascual a single quote is not a special character inside a string, not in a regex context either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't need the leading and trailing quotes in my application. `String#matches()` is not good for me (I want to reuse the pattern a LOT). The third thing seems to be the culprit though: `tes'ter` works without problems. And my analysis was incorrect: it's not an infinite loop. It seems to be exponential with regards to the number of spaces in the String! Your refactoring of the regex however delivers as expected and quicker as there are more and more spaces in the string ;) Could you please put it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: So, `String pattern = "[^']*(?:''[^']*)*"` is what you need?

Comment: As far as I understand `(?:[^']+|'')+` and `[^']*(?:''[^']*)*` are equivalent in expression, but the first one takes more and more time as the String contains more and more spaces. So, yes, I need the second one (if my understanding is correct that they are equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have hit a known issue that I described in [Java regex to match start/end tags causes stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883448/java-regex-to-match-start-end-tags-causes-stack-overflow/38883498#38883498). In brief, the reason is that Java regex engine handles quantified alternations in an inefficient way, and it is a good idea to [*unroll*](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) such patterns.

In your case, the pattern should be defined as

```
String pattern = "[^']*(?:''[^']*)*";
```

Here, the logic is *linear* and invloves much less *backtracking*:

- `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than `'`
- `(?:''[^']*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `''` - double single quote
  - `[^']*` - zero or more chars other than `'`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and source-backed answer. As I wrote in the first sentence of the question: it was a PEBKAC I did not see :)

Answer (score -1):

I think your infinite loop is elsewhere.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[^']+|'')+");

public void test(String test) {
    System.out.println("\ntest = [" + test + "]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found!");
        for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Matched (" + i + ") '" + m.group(i) + "'");
        }
    }
}

private void test() {
    test("select x, y, z where x = ''t'';");
    test("select x, y, z where x = 't'';");
    test("tes'ter");

}
```

Works fine with no issue.

JDK-1.8.0_111

Comment: See [Are “works for me” answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - *The point of an answer is that it should help the OP to solve their problem.* - I suspected OP was not iterating over the groups or the `m.find()` calls properly. This would demonstrate doing that correctly.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon the OP did not even mention `matcher#find()`, it is about `matcher#matches()`